# adjust the width of all label tabs

Tags: html, css, select, tabs

I have content with tabs 1300px wide. I can’t understand how to adjust the upper blocks with labels so that they are in one line (with a slight indent from each other, by 1px), and 100% wide, within 1300px. I provide the code of my tab, as well as the picture, as necessary, too. Thank you very much for your help![

```css
.rate_selector {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.rate_selector_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 1300px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
  margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
}

.tabs {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs>input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs>div {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#tab-btn-1:checked~#content-1,
#tab-btn-2:checked~#content-2,
#tab-btn-3:checked~#content-3,
#tab-btn-4:checked~#content-4 {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs>label {
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  top: 1px;
}

.tabs>label:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-left: none;
}

.tabs>input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FAFAFA;
}
```

```html
<div class="rate_selector">
                <div class="rate_selector_content">
                    <div class="tabs">
                        <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" value="" checked>
                        <label for="tab-btn-1">Text1</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2" value="">
                        <label for="tab-btn-2">Text2</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-3" value="">
                        <label for="tab-btn-3">Text3</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-4" value="">
                        <label for="tab-btn-4">Text4</label>
                    
                        <div id="content-1">
                          Text content 1
                        </div>
                        <div id="content-2">
                          Text content 2
                        </div>
                        <div id="content-3">
                          Text content 3
                        </div>
                        <div id="content-4">
                          Text content 4
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
  </div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P82yA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by using `flexbox` and wrapping it.

```
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Now you have everything in single line (labels and content). So you need to expand the content area by setting its width to 100%.

```
#tab-btn-1:checked~#content-1,
#tab-btn-2:checked~#content-2,
#tab-btn-3:checked~#content-3,
#tab-btn-4:checked~#content-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

So we achieved what we had in begining. Last thing to do is add flex-grow to labels to fill everything up.

```
.tabs>label {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Working [codepen](https://codepen.io/juodikis/pen/eYpwZzR)